# Jquery Mobile Navbar issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have created bottom fixed tabs using jquery mobile data-role="navbar" inside a JQ footer. The issue is it creates a div on runtime outside the  page flow which is absolute, more than the height of the page content. This is getting created on runtime and appears only when the navbar code is written. Need some help on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you viewing the website on a mobile device (and which mobile OS if so).

This issue has appeared in my experience, but only when using a standard web browser.